# Dependency injection in unit tests, how do I inject into my injected class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have a Web API project where I bind to all my classes.

```
//NinjectWebCommon.cs
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<DAL.IDAL>().To<DAL.MyDAL>();
    kernel.Bind<BUS.IService>().To<BUS.MyService>();
    kernel.Bind<DAL.IUser>().To<API.User>().InSingletonScope();
}
```

This works fine.

I tried to set up my Unit Tests for my DAL using the following.

```
//Test1.cs
public DAL.IDAL db { private get; set; }

[TestInitialize]
public void InitializeTests()
{
    var kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel();
    db = kernel.Get<DAL.MyDAL>();
    kernel.Bind<DAL.IUser>().To<Test.User>().InSingletonScope();;
}
```

I get the error

> Error activating IUser
>   No matching bindings are available and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation Path:
>     2) Injection of dependency IUser into property user of type MyDAL
>     1) Request for MyDAL

I have IUser in the MyDAL class. I'm not sure exactly what is going on here.

```
//MyDAL.cs
public class MyDAL
{
    [Inject]
    public IUser user { get; set; }

    //other functions
    //...
}
```

Comment: Should you not have re-binding `IUser` **before** you resolve `DAL.MyDal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. Thanks to this [Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/lukewickstead/DOT-NET-on-Linux/blob/master/CheatSheets/Ninject.cs)

Basically I need to specifically inject my value into my class.

```
public DAL.IDAL db { private get; set; }

[TestInitialize]
public void InitializeTests()
{
    var kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel();
    db = kernel.Get<DAL.MyDAL>(new PropertyValue("user", new Test.User());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Flip" these 2 lines.

```
db = kernel.Get<DAL.MyDAL>();
kernel.Bind<DAL.IUser>().To<Test.User>().InSingletonScope();
```

Aka:

```
kernel.Bind<DAL.IUser>().To<Test.User>().InSingletonScope();
db = kernel.Get<DAL.MyDAL>();
```

You have to "define" things before you invoke.