# How do I write a unit test where I have to dependency inject a parameter from startup.cs

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

This is the class I want to test.   It uses dependency injection to push `HandleMemoryCache` so values can be stored in in-memory cache.

```
public class HandleMemoryCache : IHandleMemoryCache {
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public HandleMemoryCache(IMemoryCache memoryCache) {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
    public void WriteEntry(string key, string value) {// writes value to the cache}
    public string ReadEntry(string key) {// reads value from cache}
}
```

This line is in Startup.cs to create the DI object.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHandleMemoryCache, HandleMemoryCache>();
```

This is the Visual Studio test project I have at the moment

```
// arrange
string key = "TestKey";
string value = "TestValue";

IHandleMemoryCache  inMemoryCache = new HandleMemoryCache (#####);

// act
inMemoryCache.WriteEntry(key, value);

// assert
Assert.That(value, Is.EqualTo(inMemoryCache.ReadEntry(key)));
```

How do I pass in or mock the object for the parameter`IMemoryCache memoryCache` where I've put #####?

I've tried this, but I'm not injecting a value into my class, I'm trying to define it.
[Dependency injection in unit tests, how do I inject into my injected class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462233/dependency-injection-in-unit-tests-how-do-i-inject-into-my-injected-class)

Comment: Currently your test code doesn't create a `HandleMemoryCache` at all. I would expect your arrange to include `HandleMemoryCache cache = new HandleMemoryCache(inMemoryCache);` then act on that. (We don't know what `InMemoryCache` is though - in particular we don't know whether it's okay to use that in your test or whether you should be mocking the `IMemoryCache` used by `HandleMemoryCache`.)

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to know how to create mock objects? If so, do you wish to learn how to do so by hand, or perhaps using a mocking framework? Or do you wish to use a real implementation of `IMemoryCache` as 'mock' and want to pull it from the DI Container. If so, explain why you need to pull it from the DI Container, and why you can't create that instance by hand inside the test. Why do you need the DI Container. Eitherway, you need to provide more context in order for anyone to provide you with a useful answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Startup.cs is instantiating `HandleMemoryCache` and if it's called directly the singleton is passed in and everything runs correctly.

Comment: But your *test* isn't using Startup, is it? At least, nowhere that you've shown us. If you just want to write a unit test for `HandleMemoryCache`, you probably don't want to use the DI from Startup. Your question is clearer now the you've made the naming consistent... but basically you need a mock `IMemoryCache` or a fake for it. The dependency injection aspect is irrelevant.

Comment: @JonSkeet So how do I unit test that the DI is working?

Comment: That would be an entirely different test to the one that you've written above. You'd probably start a test server. (And it's more integration test than unit test, really.) We don't know nearly enough about your context to know what you'd test there, but it's entirely separate to the question you're asking *here*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Testing the DI was a secondary I'm worried about later, it's just as it came up.
'IMemoryCache' is instantiated in `startup.cs` as shown above, I've got other parameters which I left out for clarity, namely `Configuration config` and `ILogger<HandleMemoryCache> logger`.  All the parameters are passed in when it's first called.

Am I supposed to instantiate an instance of HandleMemoryCache with this
`IHandleMemoryCache inMemoryCache = new HandleMemoryCache(config, memoryCache, logger);`.

And before this instantiate the objects it relies on `config, memoryCache, logger`

Comment: And then instantiate all the objects that `config, memoryCache, logger` rely on?

And so on and so on, up the code tree?

Comment: All of the objects and their antecedents that have been created automatically in `startup.cs`, I've got to manually create them somehow?

Comment: Please don't use comments to effectively ask a *completely different question*. Decide whether you want this question to be about testing DI or not, and edit it to be *just* about that one thing, without any comments about the other thing.

Comment: I didn't I was clarifying the existing being as you didn't understand the question "How do I pass in or mock the object for the parameterIMemoryCache memoryCache" ?